# How to make an image fade in 2 seconds after page is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css

So basically I have SVG image of this arrow in my website, and I already have an animation set to it with CSS, so it can move up and down.

The problem is everything fades in when the page loads (because I've added CSS animations to them) and I was hoping if someone could help me to make the arrow fade in not just appear using JavaScript.

Comment: Share your code with us

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS property `transition-delay` (supposing you are using CSS for the fading). See [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-delay.asp) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the replay bro, I was actually looking for a way to implement the fading animation using JavaScript because i've already used the CSS animation on that element for something else :)

Comment: @itsTiny ok, then you have to show us the js code with which you are making the animation !

Comment: nvm I figured it out thanks :)
Btw should i remove the post so people cannot view anymore ?

Comment: @itsTiny if you do not want to show your code, remove it, but it would be better if you would add a Minimal Reproducible Example how you solved it, and leave it for others having this problem. But if you are not going to add code to your question, delete it.

Comment: @itsTiny it would be helpful to answer your own question